# Rails find_each and each not returning all the records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a calculation against all the records in a table. But for some reason when I iterate over all the items in the table using find_each or each some of the records are not returned.

It does not happen locally where I have a few 100 records. But any time I try to run it on Heroku, it seems to skip over some of the records.

I tried running the code against individual records that were not being processed and they are processed as expected. But as soon as I put it into the find_each loop it does not work.

I also tried using IneventoryRecord.all.each but that seems to have the same problem.

I also tried printing out the records that I knew were not showing up in the results but none of the items were printed so for some reason it looks like the records are being skipped over.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

**Code**

```
class InventoryReportTable::AverageForecast

def generate
    iterate_inventory_reports
end

private
def iterate_inventory_reports
    InventoryReport.find_each do |inventory_report|

        average_lag_1_forecast = average_three_month_forecast(inventory_report.product_number, 1)
        average_lag_2_forecast = average_three_month_forecast(inventory_report.product_number, 2)

        inventory_report.average_lag_1_forecast = average_lag_1_forecast
        inventory_report.average_lag_2_forecast = average_lag_2_forecast
        inventory_report.save
    end
end

def forecasts(product_number, lag)
    extract_date_target_month_start = current_month_beginning - lag.month
    Forecast
        .where( extract_date: extract_date_target_month_start..extract_date_target_month_start.end_of_month )
        .where(final: true)
        .where( product_number: product_number )
        .where( month: current_month_beginning..(current_month_beginning + 3.months) - 1.day )
        .group(:month)  
        .sum(:quantity)
end

def average_three_month_forecast(product_number, lag)
    hash_helper = Helpers::Hash.new
    return hash_helper.average_hash( forecasts(product_number, lag) )       
end

# Helper methods
def current_month_beginning
    Date.today.beginning_of_month
end

def days_in_a_month
    return 20
end

end
```

**Edit**

I conducted a few more tests to see if I could figure out where the problem lies.

I ran a simple

```
InventoryReport.find_each do |inventory_report|
    puts inventory_report.product_number
end
```

loop to see if there any invalid characters causing problems, but that did not seem to be the case.

I also checked to make sure there were no trailing or leading spaces in the product_number and I could not find any.

Comment: When you write "seems to", I assume you're not 100% certain? What makes you think that this is the case? Also what database are you using and what kind of primary key/indexes does the `InventoryReport` model have?

Comment: When I do the calculations in Excel and check it against the calculations stored in the database, the numbers are off, the value in the database is much lower than what I am getting in Excel. Then checking the data in the database there are some records that still have a nil value when there should be an actual number there.

Comment: What database and type of primary key are you using? Batches only work when the primary key is orderable and one possible explanation would be that modifying `InventoryReport`s inside the block glitches the query for the next batch..

Comment: A tip totally unrelated to your question: you might want to add scopes to the `Forecast` class so you can write the query like this: `Forecast.final.with_lag(lag).up_to_months(3).where(product_number: product_number).sum(:quantity)`.

Comment: Thanks @ma_il for all your help. That is what I also though initially where the block was skipping items because of  the id column. But it turns out it was a time out issue on heroku.

Comment: Agreed, I need to move the query back into a scope. I had it as a scope but then when the code was not working I moved it into this class so that it would be easier to share one file and get help. Rather than having to add the scope code along with the class when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was going wrong. I was using rake to run this code on Heroku. The InventoryReport table was rather large so rake was timing out on Heroku. Although it did not throw any errors.

I ended up moving the code to a background job and it worked perfectly.